# Node.js: Identifying the file that is modified for automated test case execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, automation, nodemon, node-supervisor

I currently use [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon) or [supervisor](https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor) for automatic server restarting and automatic test cases execution. But currently my requirement is to `run specific test cases` when `certain files` are changed. For example if `app\models\user.js` is modified, I want `test\model\user-test.js` to be executed.

I order to achieve that I need to identify which are the files that are modified. How can I achieve that using `nodemon` or `supervisor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know if you can do that with nodemon or supervisor, but you always could write your own:

```
var watch = require('watch');

function methodToDoTestOnFile(file) {
  //IMPLEMENT
}

watch.createMonitor(filesToWatch, function (monitor) {
  monitor.on('changed', function (f) {
    //do some test on f
    methodToDoTestOnFile(f)
  });
});
```

Comment: It works but is there a way to set the time interval for the monitor? Currently it takes couple of seconds to emit the event.

Comment: The library use fs.watchFile, and the option interval is in the api. I guess that if you call watch.createMonitor(filesToWatch, {interval: milisecondTime}, cb), must work.